# How do I redirect from a User Message Template

Tags: forms, redirects, subscriptions, mailinglist

I am trying to figure out how to redirect users once they click on the Mailing List confirmation email link.

Currently, when someone submits their email for inclusion in a mailing list, they get an email that they must respond to by clicking on the link to activate their subscription. Unfortunately this results in a generic EE confirmation page:

[image: Email confirmation notice]

Is there any way to redirect them from here to another page on the site? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the input above, but after additional research found the handy extension from Brian Litzinger: [Custom System Messages](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/csm) which completely resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to apply some JavaScript to redirect user to another page.

Go to CP -> Design -> Message Pages -> User Messages

```
var delay = 500;
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = URL; }, delay);
```

But note, it would be effected for all the user messages. Although, you can check referrer URL with `document.referrer`

Comment: Note that the User Message template already includes a meta refresh tag which does this.

Comment: The main issue here is that the user has to respond to an email before they can be forwarded to the final destination URL. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The older 3.X version of Solspace Freeform allowed you to add email addresses of submitted forms to any EE mailing list of your choice. You could replace your existing mailing list signup form with a Freeform form to add users to the list. Then you can use Freeform's "return" param to decide exactly where they go after sign up.

Comment: You can do this with the current Freeform http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#mailinglist but I think that doesn't solve the issue coming from the confirmation email. I haven't used this add-on but it may be helpful: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages In the past I've hacked EE to eliminate the double opt-in, but there is such intense targeting of EE installations by spammers now, I wouldn't recommend that.